# Add "Go get it" button for Archaeologist

Tags: feature-request, badges

Archaeologist badge is missing `Go get it` button which will give a list of relevant post I can edit to achieve this badge.

Especially that this badge isn't very clear as written in [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184009/why-have-i-not-received-the-archaeologist-badge):

> I think this badge needs a lot more clarification from the devs

Others badges have it, as Socratic and Inquisitive.

Comment: How is Stack Overflow supposed to provide a list of posts that should be edited? What qualifies? We don't want to have people make unnecessary edits

Comment: Oh, and for the ones that really want the badge: correct aray to array in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=aray+lastactive%3A5y...6m) (2K + rep of course, no trivial edits for the queue)

Comment: The badge must have a value to it (even an hidden one), I suggest Posts not active for 6 months maybe sort by interesting and maybe filtered by mine tags

Comment: BTW I read the minimal edits as typo probably aren't consider for this badge

Comment: That encourages people to edit random historic/interesting posts, which can be very harmful, especially on inactive posts where the OP isn't there to correct harmful edits

Comment: Afaik tag-only edits don't count, any edits to the content of the post should count

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [Add “Go get it” button for “Archaeologist” badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303136/295232)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been requested on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303136/295232) as well, and because I can't close this question as a duplicate of that one, I'll quote [wythagoras](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/298374/wythagoras)' answer:

> While this could be a good idea (just to be consistent), I don't think this was really meant to be a badge to "Go get it". This badge is more meant to be an encouragement to think about editing when you are browsing old posts. At least, that is how I made progress towards this badge: I read a lot of old posts, and if I see something I can improve, then I do so.
>
> It is generally not a good idea to randomly start editing old posts, since this floods the "last active" page. While one or two edits are not a problem, more than that push fresh questions off the list, which is a problem, especially on small (beta) sites.